# Text element in animated SVG moves in stuttering motion

Tags: animation, svg, text, rendering

Basic geometrical SVG elements can be positioned at fractions of a pixel, but apparently not so `text` elements as the example script demonstrates. While the motion of the `rect` element is smooth, the `text` element's motion is more like stuttering, probably because the position is rounded to the next full pixel so the text does not appear blurry due to anti-aliasing issues or so. But in this context of *moving* text this rounding does not make sense but causes the stuttering motion. This is just a guess, maybe I am wrong.

Does anyone have a solution how to make the motion of the `text` element as smooth as the `rect` element's? Thank you.

```html
<html>
  <svg width="800" height="800">
    <rect x='0' y='0' width='250' height='50' fill='none' stroke='black' stroke-width='4' />
    <text x='0' y='0' fill='black' font-size='40' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'>Hello, world!</text>
  </svg>
  <script>
    function moveElements() {
      document.getElementsByTagName("rect")[0].setAttribute("x", p);
      document.getElementsByTagName("rect")[0].setAttribute("y", p);
      document.getElementsByTagName("text")[0].setAttribute("x", p + 125);
      document.getElementsByTagName("text")[0].setAttribute("y", p + 38);
      p += .1;
    }
    p = 0;
    setInterval(moveElements, 20);
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this behaviour only occurs when the text's baseline is parallel to the pixel grid, or in other words: exactly horizontal, the issue can be worked around by rotating the text by a tiny fraction hardly visible to the eye but big enough to escape the pixel grid, like so (not too elegant, more a hack, but works for me):

```html
<html>
  <svg width="800" height="800">
    <rect x='0' y='0' width='250' height='50' fill='none' stroke='black' stroke-width='4' />
    <text x='0' y='0' fill='black' font-size='40' font-weight='bold' text-anchor='middle'>Hello, world!</text>
  </svg>
  <script>
    function moveElements() {
      document.getElementsByTagName("rect")[0].setAttribute("x", p);
      document.getElementsByTagName("rect")[0].setAttribute("y", p);
      document.getElementsByTagName("text")[0].setAttribute("x", p + 125);
      document.getElementsByTagName("text")[0].setAttribute("y", p + 38);
      document.getElementsByTagName("text")[0].setAttribute("transform", "rotate(.05 " + (p + 125) + " " + (p + 25) + ")");
      p += .1;
    }
    p = 0;
    setInterval(moveElements, 20);
  </script>
</html>
```